# What does "count.get" mean in Leetcode 347. Top K Frequent Elements

Tags: python, algorithm, collections, counter, heap

In the solution of the problem (Leet code 347. Top K Frequent Elements)

Given an integer array nums and an integer k, return the k most frequent elements. You may return the answer in any order.

```
from collections import Counter
class Solution:
    def topKFrequent(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:  
        if k == len(nums):
            return nums
        
        count = Counter(nums)   
        return heapq.nlargest(k, count.keys(), key=count.get)
```

I cannot understand what

```
key=count.get
```

means at the last line.

When the input is

```
nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3], k = 2
```

the answer should be

```
[1,2]
```

If I cut

```
key=count.get
```

from the last line,
the output would be

```
[3,2]
```

Could anyone teach me what "count.get" does?

Comment: `count` is a `collections.Counter` object, which, according to the documentation, is a sublclass of `dict`, which documents the method. What do you find unclear? The documentation about get? The use of a `key` for sorting?

Comment: `key` determines the "attribute" to compare while sorting, `count.get` returns frequency of the element